# Нужно сложить элементы матрицы. Выдает ошибку error C2110: +:

Tags: c++, массивы, операторы

Мне нужно сложить элементы матрицы.

Выдает ошибку error C2110: +: невозможно добавить два указателя -

помогите пожалуйста

```
for(int i = 3 ; i< G ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1 ; j <7; j++)
    {
        Matrix[i][j] = (Matrix[i-1,j]) + Matrix[i-1,j];
    }

}
```

Comment: как объявлена _Matrix_? и почему в одном случае используется _[i][j]_ а в другом _[i-1,j]_?

Comment: по тому что мне надо сложить два последних и получить новый

Comment: я хотел обратить внимание не на значения которые вы используете, а на скобочки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в строке

```
Matrix[i][j] = (Matrix[i-1,j]) + Matrix[i-1,j];
```

Конкретно вы не правильно используете оператор `[]`

так как у вас массив массивов, то `Matrix[a]` вернет **указатель**, а не значение.

поэтому нужно заменить

```
Matrix[i-1,j] ; Matrix[i-1,j]
```

на

```
Matrix[i-1][j] ; Matrix[i-1][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении

```
    Matrix[i][j] = (Matrix[i-1,j]) + Matrix[i-1,j];
                           ::::::          :::::::
```

в квадратных скобках у вас используется оператор запятая. Фактически это предложение полностью эквивалентно следующему

```
    Matrix[i][j] = (Matrix[j]) + Matrix[j];
```

Выражение `Matrix[j]` - это указатель, а не элемент массива. Поэтому имеет место сложение двух указателей, что невозможно в C++, так как такая операция не определена.

Так что ваш код неверен. Вы должны сначала разобраться, что вы пытаетесь сделать.